# How to create proper as3 external file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, actionscript

Hello guys i've been trying since days to understand how to create many as3 file and be able to use them from my main.as file cause there is way too much code. I tryed to look over internet but i don't understand anything.

For example i made this loginScreen.as which i wanna use from my main when my game start. The main.as file would show that screen. What i'm trying to do is this:

From main.as

```
import as3.loginScreen;
...
var loginscreen:loginScreen = new loginScreen();
addChild(loginscreen);
```

Now this is my loginScreen.as

```
package as3
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public class loginScreen
{

    public function loginScreen()
    {
        var loginBG:MovieClip = new LoginBG();
        loginBG.x = 0;
        loginBG.y = 0;
        loginScreen.addChild(loginBG);

        var txt_Username:TextField = new TextField();
        var txt_Password:TextField = new TextField();
        var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

        //myTextFormat.font = "Arial";
        myTextFormat.size = 15;
        myTextFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;

        txt_Username.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
        txt_Password.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;

        txt_Username.border = false;
        txt_Username.width = 114;
        txt_Username.height = 20;
        txt_Username.x = 323;
        txt_Username.y = 431;

        txt_Password.border = false;
        txt_Password.width = 114;
        txt_Password.height = 20;
        txt_Password.x = 323;
        txt_Password.y = 461;

        txt_Username.defaultTextFormat = myTextFormat;
        txt_Password.defaultTextFormat = myTextFormat;

        loginScreen.addChild(txt_Username);
        loginScreen.addChild(txt_Password);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the class definition of loginScreen to :

```
public class loginScreen extends Sprite
```

Then change `loginScreen.addChild(loginBG);` to `addChild(loginBG);` same with the other two.

```
loginScreen.addChild(txt_Username);
loginScreen.addChild(txt_Password);
```

Needs to be :

```
addChild(txt_Username);
addChild(txt_Password);
```

`loginScreen` is the name of the class it doesn't make sense to try and add children to it.

Also it is good practice to start class names with a capital letter so you don't confuse them with variables, so you might want to change `class loginScreen` to `class LoginScreen`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: finaly it work! thanks alot!

I knew it was something with extends class but didnt know how to do it so i was trying to set the stage definition or something with the loginScreen.addchild... got way too confused lol :)

Ill finaly clear this code in my project and continue in a good way! :)